# How to deny url based on role

Tags: spring-security

I have list of users which have multiple roles. I am looking basically opposite of hasAuthority('systemAccessRole') for example if user have systemAccessRole i want to block him on some url.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/url/global/*" access="hasAuthority('systemAccessRole')"/>

// user will not allowed to access domestic url if he/she has role  systemAccessRole
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/url/domestic/*" access="hasAuthority('systemAccessRole')"/>
```

What would be a expression i can use in that case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `!` (`not`) operator:

```xml
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/url/domestic/*" access="!hasAuthority('systemAccessRole')"/>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i tried first before posting here. But somehow i need both access="isAuthenticated() and !hasAuthority('systemAccessRole')" and then it work like charm.

Comment: [15.2 Web Security Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) shares an examples.